# Как мне обновить python 3.5 на 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, debian

второй день воюю с обновлением, нужно накатить на сервер новую версию python, но она не встает, постоянно выскакивают ошибки, можно хоть 3.7 накатить, главное выше 3.5.

Ошибки вида http://prntscr.com/ri92wl

У меня сервер VPS:

```
Distributor ID: Debian                                                                                                                
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch)                                                                                       
Release:        9.12                                                                                                                  
Codename:       stretch
```

В файле source.list у меня сейчас 1 запись

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian testing main
```

Начинаю устанавливать пакеты, также всплывают ошибки:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpq-dev libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev zlib1g-dev                              
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                         
E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Comment: По предложенной ссылке не могу установить Anaconda:root@sanitarn:~# apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libx
i6 libxtst6                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release

Comment: Просто установите нужную версию питона параллельно и используйте его для вызова своих приложений

Comment: Как? я уже 10 инструкций перепробовал, ничего не ставится. Когда установил 3.6 решил запустить, но опять же ошибка http://prntscr.com/ri9wsd

Comment: А почему не сразу 3.8?

Comment: Готов поставить 3.8, подскажите только как, можно пруф? Честно впервые устанавливаю, обычно сразу все пакеты были установлены.

Comment: Я не имел дела с чистым debian, но если не работает sudo apt install python3.8, то сбор из исходников. Главное не пытаться обновить системный питон.

Comment: Попробуйте отредактировать source.list чтобы было как здесь: https://unixhelp.org/debian-9-default-reposytory/ После редактирование не забудьте сделать `sudo apt-get update`. После этого уже пробуйте устанавливать python.

Comment: @insolor не встает, при обновление пакетов в конце ошибки http://prntscr.com/ribne0 а после все равно
                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                       
E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

Comment: @sanitarn, тогда в директории `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` во всех файлах удалить строки с упоминаниями ppa.launchpad.net, после этого опять сделать `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @insolor сделал http://prntscr.com/rifqfx , вроде апдейт прошел норм, но после стал устанавливать пакеты и снова такая же ошибка. Хостер сообщил типо это поможет https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543407/the-value-stable-is-invalid-for-aptdefault-release-as-such-a-release-is-not , но в каком файле делать изменения я не понимаю http://prntscr.com/rifshp

Comment: @insolor В общем проблему решил, нужно было лишнюю строчку с stable удалить в файле 00local . Спасибо вам за помощь!